# Merging all elements in a list into one single element

Tags: python

I'm trying to merge elements in a list, into one single element back into the list.

For instance I have a list:

`fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']`

How do I merge all of them to become, let's say:

`fruits = ['apple orange grape']`

or

`fruits = ['appleorangegrape']`

or even

`fruits ['apple, orange, grape']`

Thank you in advance!!

So far thought about concat(), but it works for list to list, not for combining elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']

fruits_str = ' '.join(fruits)
print(fruits_str) # for 'apple orange grape'

fruits_str = ''.join(fruits)
print(fruits_str)  # for 'appleorangegrape'

fruits_str = ', '.join(fruits)
print(fruits_str)  # for 'apple, orange, grape'
```